# Firefox 65.0 resize tabs height to make tabs touched the top of the screen?

Tags: 18.04, firefox

- Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
- GNOME 3.28.2
- Firefox Quantum 65.0 (64-bit), Mozilla Firefox for Ubuntu canonical-0.1

After update from **Firefox Quantum 64** stop working old hack from https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/959205
where I must add **userChrome.css** with code:
`#TabsToolbar { height: 35px !important; }`
and save it as `~/.mozilla/firefox/something.default/chrome/userChrome.css`

### I repeat what the problem looks like..

Now we have again:

[image: Firefox tab with couple of pixels from top of screen]

But it is more convenient when we do not need to get exactly mouse cursor to tab. Is more useful because intuitively we more often collide the top surface of the screen before.

Good solution:

[image]

Or same in Google Chrome:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Launch Firefox, go to the '**Customise**' screen, and disable the "*Drag Space*" option (next to "*Title Bar*") at the bottom:

[image]

Comment: In my case "Drag Space" was **unchecked**

Comment: Strange! In my case the difference is very noticeable: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8YUVw.png

Answer (score 0):

Ok, when I reset all my Firefox custom settings and styles, i found solution:

1. Need to disable **Drag Space** if enabled.
2. Go to **Density** selection:

[image: Drag Space & Density]

3. For my case I select Density = **Touch** and click Done button:

### Compact:

[image: Compact Density]

### Normal:

[image: Normal Density]

### Touch:

[image: Touch Density]

Comment: "Touch" makes everything taller leading to more waste of screen real estate.